# How to toggle svg elements using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, svg

I need to toggle between two `svg`'s inserted with the `ng-include` directive.

Basically, I want to transform this:

```
<i class="indicator oppcicon {{domain.show_requests ? 'icon-chevron-down' : 'icon-chevron-right'}}"></i>
```

In something like this:

```
<i ng-include class="indicator" src="{{domain.show_requests ? 'images/chevron-down.svg' : 'images/chevron-right.svg'}}" ></i>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
<i class="indicator" ng-include="domain.show_requests ? 'images/chevron-down.svg' : 'images/chevron-right.svg'" ></i>
```